# How is that this.state in react acts as an Async and Await function?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, state

I was told here that `this.state` is acting as async, that I can not await it as it would go further anyhow, this looked to be through in most of the cases, but didn't go into detail. Though now if I write:

```
  pictureHandle = async ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    console.log("File Handle is called!");
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      let item = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[i]);
      await this.setState({
        files: [...this.state.files, item],
      });
    }
    console.log(this.state.files);
  };
```

The console.log shows three items [e.g. I selected three files/pictures], but if I use this [difference in await], then the state would not yet be set.

```
  pictureHandle = async ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    console.log("File Handle is called!");
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      let item = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[i]);
       this.setState({
        files: [...this.state.files, item],
      });
    }
    console.log(this.state.files);
  };
```

So this says that `this.state` can be used with `await`, or is there anything in the code which is wrong? If I take away the async from the function I don't get anything in console.log, and I cannot use await.

Comment: `async-await` used for promises, `setState` is not a promise

Comment: state is updated asynchronously, logging it immediately after calling `this.setState()` will not log the new value of the state. As far as using `await` before `this.setState` is concerned, its useless because `this.setState` doesn't returns a promise, so you can't `await` it.

Comment: Yes, but why does the console log out the state if I await it because the code should not be any different if I use the await or not then.

Comment: There was already a thread about that, AFAIK its related with event loop. So firstly `setState` executes, however it's used with `await` keyword so its auto-wrapped by a promise. And by `promise.resolve()` on `setState` is called, the data in state has been updated so the console logs correct data.

Comment: Perfect answer! So I wrap the `setState` with Promise once I use await! Thanks!